# C Struct Array Input

Tags: c, printf, scanf, gets, puts

I have the following struct

```
typedef char String[256];

typedef struct
{
    String name;
    int year;
    float price;
} Book;
```

Array of Books

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{    
    Book books[5];

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        books[i] = inputBook();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

inputBook() function

```
Book inputBook()
{
    Book myBook;

    //Name
    puts("Enter Book Name:");
    gets(myBook.name);

    //Publishing Year
    puts("Enter Book Publishing Year:");
    scanf("%i", &myBook.year);

    //Price
    puts("Enter Book Price:");
    scanf("%f", &myBook.price);

    return myBook;
}
```

For some reason the first book input is going well but when trying to input the second book and the second call to `inputBook()` I can set a book name, it jumps straight to the year import.

What is the problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: typedef char String[256];

C Code

Comment: is it happening also on debug?

Comment: I think you forget to count byte of the new data. If byte of new data < reserved place, it will happen

Comment: Forgive me, type error not "<", correct one ">" . Correct sentence will be " If byte of new data > reserved place, it will happen"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To correct, replace:

```
gets(myBook.name);
```

with:

```
scanf("%255s", myBook.name); /* 255 as name is 256 chars. */
```

as `scanf()` will skip any whitespace characters, but `gets()` will not. A newline character is considered a whitespace character and there will be a newline remaining in `stdin` after the `price` has been entered causing `gets()` to read the newline and effectively read nothing.

Worth reading: [warning:gets function is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843073/warninggets-function-is-dangerous)

Comment: but `scanf("%255s", myBook.name);` doesn't scan multiple words. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379141/c-multiple-words-input-using-scanf)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the variable myBook is valid only in the inputBook scope and is destroyed as soon as the function exits.

you should pass the book item you want to initialize as a parameter of your function.

function inputBook()...

```
void inputBook(Book *ptBook )
{
    if( ptBook==NULL )
        return;

    //Name
    puts("Enter Book Name:");
    gets(ptBook->name);

    //Publishing Year
    puts("Enter Book Publishing Year:");
    scanf("%i", &ptBook->year);

    //Price
    puts("Enter Book Price:");
    scanf("%f", &ptBook->price);
}
```

The main function...

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{    
    Book books[5];

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        inputBook( &books[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But the return value is being copied, no? Which is ok (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302351/assign-one-struct-to-another-in-c).

Comment: It depends on the compiler...e.g. SDCC does not support this feature. http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sdcc/wiki/Standard%20compliance

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to flush stdin before next iteration. You have orevious CRLF in your stdin stream.

use fflush(stdin); in the beginning of loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try fflush(stdin) before input.

```
Book inputBook()
{
    Book myBook;

    fflush(stdin);

    // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Flushing `stdin` is undefined behavior AFAIK. `fflush` is generally intended for output streams.

Comment: @PavanManjunath To avoid using fflush(stdin), one can write a short func to read all bytes in stdin. That solves the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char String[256];

typedef struct
{
    String name;
    int year;
    float price;
    } Book;
Book inputBook()
{
    Book myBook;

    //Name
    puts("Enter Book Name:");
    getchar();
    gets(myBook.name);

    //Publishing Year
    puts("Enter Book Publishing Year:");
    scanf("%i", &myBook.year);

    //Price
    puts("Enter Book Price:");
    scanf("%f", &myBook.price);

    return myBook;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Book books[5];

int i = 0; for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    books[i] = inputBook();
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: at the usage of fflush(stdin): i have point to make.. ! 
you can also use, fgetc.. as well as if you are using gcc.. fflush might not be supporting..