# copy data from one structure to another in C

Tags: c, structure, memcpy

If I have a structure defined like:

```
struct image{
unsigned int width, height;
unsigned char *data;
};
```

And 2 variables of this type:

```
struct image image1;
struct image image2;
```

I want to transfer the data from image1 to the data of image2(presuming image1 has some data written, and image2 has data allocated with malloc or calloc). How can it be done? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is duplicating **the struct** (i. e. creating a "shallow" copy):

```
image2 = image1;
```

if you also want to copy **the data** pointed to by `image1.data` ("deep copy"), then you need to do that manually:

```
memcpy(image2.data, image1.data, image1.width * image1.height);
```

(assuming there are `image1.width * image1.height` bytes in the data, and there's enough space `malloc()`ated in `image2.data` for storing that.)

Comment: With this `image2.data` will point to `image1.data` which is not correct. Each member should be copied separately.

Comment: @H2CO3 The shallow copy section might benefit from a mention that any allocated `data` member of `image2` would be leaked.

Comment: @Rohan Huh what? "With this" - with what?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming it is undesirable that two instances of `struct image` are pointing to the same `data` then `memcpy()` cannot be used to copy the `structs`. To copy:

- allocate memory for destination struct
- allocate memory for destination `data` buffer based on source `data`
- assign `width` members
- `memcpy()` `data` members.

For example:

```
struct image* deep_copy_image(const struct image* img)
{
    struct image* result = malloc(sizeof(*result));
    if (result)
    {
        /* Assuming 'width' means "number of elements" in 'data'. */
        result->width = img->width;
        result->data = malloc(img->width);
        if (result->data)
        {
            memcpy(result->data, img->data, result->width);
        }
        else
        {
            free(result);
            result = NULL;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: assign `height` member. `result->height`, typo?

Answer (score 2):

did you try memcpy(&image1,&image2,sizeof(image));

edit:
Alocate data for image2.data 
 after that you have to strcpy(image2.data,image1.data) if data is null terminated, but if its not, then use memcpy with the size of data.

Regards,
Luka

Comment: There's no typedef of `struct image` so that `sizeof` will throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct image image1;
struct image image2;

...

image2.width = image1.width;
image2.height = image1.height;

/* assuming data size is width*height bytes, and image2.data has enough space allocated: */

memcpy(image2.data, image1.data, width*height);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple in C. Simply do the following (assuming image2 is uninitialized):

```
image2 = image1;  //there's no deep copy, pointed to memory isn't copied
```

You can assign one structure variable to other given they are of the same type. No need to copy piece-meal. This is a useful feature of C.

This has been discussed before:

[Assign one struct to another in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302351/assign-one-struct-to-another-in-c)

Comment: -1.  Sorry, but this leaks any existing `data` member of `image2`.  If you assume that `image2` is effectively uninitialised before this assignment, it'll be important to say this explicitly.

Comment: @simonc You contradict the link above, and the answer with 26 upvotes.

Comment: I don't think I contradict that question - this is just a slightly more complex situation.  The [most popular answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2302357/311966) to that question hints at the problems you'll run into when your structs own dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @simonc Before we wrap up,please give me a short but rigorous difference between shallow copy and deep copy.I think I am fuzzy about that.

Comment: Shallow copy - copy struct members, including addresses of pointer members.  Deep copy - copy by-value members, allocate copies of pointer members that own memory, copy addresses of pointer members that don't own memory.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @simonc Plz elaborate more on `allocate copies of pointer members that own memory, copy addresses of pointer members that don't own memory`.

Comment: @simonc Please elaborate on that part of your comment.

Comment: For the struct in this question, a shallow copy of `data` would just involve `image2.data = image1.data;`.  If `image2.data` had previously pointed to malloced data, this would be leaked.  A deep copy might involve something like `free(image2.data); image2.data = malloc(image1.width * image1.height); memcpy(image2.data, image1.data, image1.width * image1.height);`

Comment: @simonc Thank you read-coat!!Else I would have had to read a lot of pages to make sense of that.Red-coat or kilt?