# Copying one value from one struct camp into another struct but same data type

Tags: c, struct

So I have one struct and I initialized a variable `A` with that struct data type then Ι put in some values. But now Ι need to take those values and put it into another variable `B` with the same struct data type. How can Ι achieve this?

```
struct s_Especialidade{
    int id;
    char nome[60];  
    char descricao[60];
    struct s_Especialidade *proximo;
}; 
typedef struct s_Especialidade  Especialidade;

PESPECIALIDADE p, *array;
p->nome = &array[i]->nome; //THIS LINE GIVES THE ERROR
```

Comment: use `strcpy` or `strncpy`

Answer (score 1):

Since it is an array of characters, you need to copy each element of the array.

`strcpy(p->nome, array[i]->nome)` will do it, but for extra security look at `strncpy` where you can set a maximum length to avoid overruns.

Answer (score 1):

Try that way :

```
memcpy( p->nome, array[i].nome, 60 * sizeof(char) );
```

Or generalizing the type as well, picking the type used in the `p->nome` array :

```
memcpy( p->nome, array[i].nome, 60 * sizeof(*(p->nome)) );
```

This is the generalized and secure way to copy an array into another (not only for strings).

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1 so multiplying by it achieves nothing. If you're trying to be general, use `60 * sizeof *p->nome`

Comment: You are perfectly right, but I still wanted to keep it clear for the OP who is a beginner. Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the answer recommending `strcpy()` I'd use `memcpy()` and use a #defined length to make sure you always use the same value.

```
#define NOME_LENGTH 60    

struct s_Especialidade{
    int id;
    char nome[NOME_LENGTH];  
    char descricao[60];     
    struct s_Especialidade *proximo;
}; 
typedef struct s_Especialidade  Especialidade;

PESPECIALIDADE p, *array; 

memcpy(p->nome, array[i]->nome, NOME_LENGTH);
```

Things get even more complicated trying to consider what an assignment does, but, in an example program:

```
struct stuff {
    char buf[2];
};

int main() {
    struct stuff a;
    memcpy(a.buf, "aa", 2); // *Edit: "aa" is a bad example as it 
                            // actually becomes at compilation 3 bytes long 
                            // {'a','a','\0'} as noted in the comments

    struct stuff b;
    b.buf = a.buf; // *Edit: For illustrative purposes, an assignment 
                   // between two char[2] members is not correct and
                   // does not compile.
}
```

Compilation yeilds the error `error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[2]’ from type ‘char *’` for the `b.buf = a.buf` line.

The topic of pointers and arrays has been covered elsewhere, [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c?lq=1) among others.

*Edit: As noted in the comments, in the above code if instead of `b.buf = a.buf;` the struct assignemnt `b = a;` were done, the internal members would be copied correctly. This is because struct to struct assignment is effectively `memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(b));` ([Assign one struct to another in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302351/assign-one-struct-to-another-in-c))

Comment: `char buf[3];` because string `"aa"` is terminated by `'\0'` ! You have 3 chars to copy.

Comment: @Golgauth It isn't relevant that "aa" is terminated by `'\0'`, since only 2 chars are being copied from it and the destination is only 2 chars long. buf won't be NUL-terminated but that's a different matter.

Comment: "Compilation yeilds the error " -- so do `a = b;` instead ... that works fine.

Comment: @JimBalter Yes, I know that was just for a pedagogic purpose. In case someone read this page and tries to manipulate C strings from that.I'm not busy right now so... ;-)