# What does the = operator do when we use it on two structs?

Tags: c++, struct

I have the following code;

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Slog1
{
    char ime1;
    int broj1;
};

struct Slog2
{
    char ime2;
    int broj2;
};
int main()
{
    Slog1 aSlog, bSlog;
    Slog2 cSlog;

    aSlog = bSlog; // 1
    bSlog.ime1 = cSlog.ime2; // 2
    aSlog = cSlog; // 3

}
```

Now, I have declared:

```
Slog1 aSlog, bSlog;
Slog2 cSlog;
```

Those are struct variables which I understand very well. And now I have these:

```
aSlog = bSlog; // 1
bSlog.ime1 = cSlog.ime2; // 2
aSlog = cSlog; // 3
```

1. What does it do exactly? It compiles fine but I'm not sure it does.
2. This one I understand well, it sets the member ime1 of bSlog the
   value of the member ime2 in the cSlog struct.
3. Doesn't compile for some reason, but it's the same as 1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302351/assign-one-struct-to-another-in-c

Comment: @akonsu What does the same 'type' mean? Can you elaborate?

Comment: "the same type" means that you can assign one variable to another if they are the same structures (types), and you cannot do it if they are different as in your third case.

Comment: Well, they are the same type, aren't they? Both have an int and char defined inside.

Comment: 1 and 3 are not the same because the structure is different (the property names).  When you say, "this object" = "that object" you're changing the memory pointed to point to the other.

Comment: they are not the same type, they are different types although these two types have similar members.

Comment: Oh, you mean the name "Slog1" and "Slog2" right?

Comment: yes, `Slog1` and `Slog2` are different types.

Comment: Do **NOT** close this as a duplicate of a `c`-tagged question!  There may well be an existing good Q&A for C++, but C++ and C differ greatly in this regard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
aSlog = bSlog; // 1
```

Each member of `aSlog` will be set to the corresponding value of `bSlog`.  This is a shallow copy, so any pointers that may be in this structure will be set to the same value.  Since `aSlog` and `bSlog` are the same type, this is an implicit copy-assignment operator.

```
bSlog.ime1 = cSlog.ime2; // 2
```

This will set the `ime1` member of `bSlog` to the value of `ime2` of the `cSlog`.  This uses the copy-assignment operator for `char`.

```
aSlog = cSlog; // 3
```

This should not compile as there is nothing in this code that tells the compiler how to convert a type of `Slog1` into a type of `Slog2`.  You would need a conversion constructor (a constructor declared in `Slog1` that takes a `Slog2` parameter).

```
struct Slog2
{
    char ime2;
    int broj2;
};

struct Slog1
{
    char ime1;
    int broj1;
    // ...
    // conversion-constructor
    Slog1(const Slog2& s2) : ime1(s2.ime2), broj1(s2.broj2)
    { }
    // copy-assignment conversion
    Slog1& operator=(const Slog2& s2)
    {
        ime1 = s2.ime2;
        broj1 = s2.broj2;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: I'd structure the first paragraph differently: Since they're of the same type, and there's no user-provided assignment operator, the implicitly generated default copy-assignment op will be used. This implicitly generated operator does a member-wise copy assignment.

Comment: *Nit-pick* (another one ;) `void operator=(const Slog2& s2)` I'd argue that this isn't a conversion (see [class.conv]/1), and the return type should (per convention) be `Slog1&`. It's not an implicit conversion because `Slog2 x; Slog1 temp = x;` is not well-formed, and none of the standard casts (`static_cast` etc., C-style casts) allow something like `(Slog1)x` via only the assignment op.

Comment: @DyP I'm not sure I follow you on the well-formed part.  The reason I didn't give it a return value is that it would be inconsistent, but there is nothing stopping him from doing it (I was just providing an example).

Comment: If you only had the copy assignment op, then `Slog2 x; Slog1 y = x;` would be ill-formed. OTOH, if you only have the converting ctor, then `Slog2 x; Slog1 y; y = x;` *is* well-formed (by constructing a temporary of type `Slog` from `x` and assigning this temporary). -- What should the return type of the assignment op be inconsistent with?

Comment: I show both being implemented, so it should be well-formed all the way around.  But what should an `operator=` return if its parameters are `type1` and `type2`?  That is, should it return a `type1`, or a `type2`?

Comment: @Zac: It should `return *this;`

Comment: @BenVoigt In general, I get that ... my point is when you have `type1 = type2` chaining it to `type1 = type2 = type3` makes little sense.

Answer (score 3):

`Slog1` and `Slog2` are completely unrelated types. No matter if you give them the same layout, the compiler will reject to assign one from the other, as long you're not providing explicit **conversion constructors** / **assignment operators** / **cast operators**.

Answer (score 3):

```
aSlog = bSlog; // 1
```

You didn't overload the assignment operator for class `Slog1`, so this uses the implicitly-declared and implicitly-defined assignment operator member function. The implicitly-defined assignment operator does a shallow copy.

```
aSlog = cSlog; // 3
```

The classes `Slog1` and `Slog2` are unrelated, so this won't compile as-is because you didn't define a mechanism to perform this assignment. You could do this with an assignment operator in class `Slog1` that receives a `Slog2` as an argument, a converting constructor in class `Slog1` that takes a `Slog2` as an argument, or an `operator Slog1` in class `Slog2` that produces a `Slog1` as an output.

Comment: No the implicitly-defined assignment operator does not "do a shallow copy".  It calls the type-appropriate assignment operator for each member.

Answer (score 2):

1. Values from bSlog are copied to aSlog
2. aSlog is of type Slog1 and cSlog is of type Slog2 that means different types that is like you will add char value to int variable

Answer (score 2):

1. It simply sets the aSlog (of type Slog1) equal to bSlog (which is also of type Slog1). This works perfectly. It is just as simple as setting one int equal to another int.
2. You are correct. This works because Slog1.ime1 and Slog2.ime2 are both of type char.
3. This is completely different from (1). cSlog is a different type than aSlog (Slog2 for c, Slog1 for a), and you can not set a Slog1 equal to a Slog2. That is the equivalent of setting a char equal to an int.

JUst a comment: pick better names than slog, ime, and broj. Just use people. Slog1 is a male, char ime1 is his first initial, and int broj1 is his age. Slog2 is a female, and the rest is the same. Then you will understand that you can not set aSlog (a Male) equal to cSlog (a Female).

Comment: `char` is implicitly convertible to an `int` - that is not a good example to use.

Comment: But not vice versa (at least without losing a ton of precision).

Comment: It will still let you do it (albeit with a warning).  Your Male = Female example is more clear and conveys the problem more completely.