# Assign pointer instances of structures in C

Tags: c, struct

Now I know from this post about [assigning one struct to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302351/assign-one-struct-to-another-in-c) that I can assign a struct variable to another one of the same type and a **shallow** copy will happen.

```
struct Test t1;
struct Test t2;
t2 = t1;
```

But what if I do this?

```
struct Test *t1;
struct Test *t2;
t1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Test));
t2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Test));
//assign t1 and t2's fields some data
*t2 = *t1;
```

Will the same memcpy happen in this case?

Comment: Of the pointer, yes. What it *points to*, no (and as written, `t1` is indeterminate anyway, so its UB to even eval it).

Comment: Oh yes, that's what I meant. I'll edit the question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following

```
*t2 = *t1;
```

will indeed be doing a shallow copy. Basically, the `*` operators on pointers act as if you were using the pointed value.

But be sure to allocate memory and define values for those or you'll get an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the types involved with both assignments are the same, so it follows that the effects of that assignment are also the same (assuming that `t1` and `t2` point to valid objects in the latter example).