# Pointer issue about Objective-C objects

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nsobject

The general use pattern for passing `NSError` is using pointer to pointer like this:

```
- (id)doSomethingWithObj:(NSObject *)obj error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{

    NSLog(@"error parameter: %p", error);
    id object = obj;
    if (object != nil)
    {
        return object;
    }
    else
    {
        NSError *tmp = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"after" code:0 userInfo:@{@"after": @"boris"}];
        *error = tmp;
        return nil;
    }
}
```

I know that since passing the address of the outside `error` pointer would allocate or replace the origin `error`, the above pattern would work.

But my issue about `NSError` or, more generic, `Objective-C` objects, is that, why I would get error if I wrote like this:

[image]

Instead of using `NSError **`, I tried `NSError *`, and what I was thinking is that, since now the parameter `error` is a type of `NSError *`, so `*error` should be the content that the pointer (error) was pointing to, then `*error = [NSError errorWith...];` could replace the origin outside `*error` content.

But it didn't work like what I was thinking but popped up such above error.

So what confused me is that why `*error = [NSError errorWith...];` does not work for the type of `NSError *` but work for `NSError **`.

Comment: Quick note;  you need `if (error) *error = tmp;`.   I.e. you must check to see if `error` is non-`nil` before assigning to it.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a parameter into a method it is copied and later inside your method you deal with that copy:

```
- (void)changeA:(NSInteger)aToChange {
    aToChange = 7;
}
```

Then, when you use that method you won't be able to change the value you passed from the inside of that method:

```
NSInteger a = 42;
[smb changeA:a];
// a is still 42
```

That's because inside `-changeA:` you deal with a copy of arguments, i.e. so you do something like (pseudo code):

```
// inside changeA:
NSInteger aToChange = a; // (value is copied)
aToChange = 7; // this does not modify a, right?
```

You might even get the address of that `aToChange` and try to do something with it:

```
// inside changeA:
NSInteger aToChange = a; // (value is copied)
NSInteger *pointerToCOPY = &aToChange; // get address of aToChange
NSInteger *pointerToA = &a; // get address of a
// here pointerToCOPY != pointerToA
```

So, going back to your code:

```
NSError *error = nil; // outer error, passed as a parameter
...
- (id)doSomethingWithObj:(NSObject *)obj error:(NSError *)error
{
    // NSError *error(local copy) = error(passed argument);
    error = tmp; // here error is the pointer to the local error copy
    return nil;
}
```

As it was before with `aToChange`, you can't modify your external `NSError error *` from inside your method. That's why double pointers are used, you send pointer to your pointer, so that you still have access to the external `error` reference and can set it.

```
- (id)doSomethingWithObj:(NSObject *)obj error:(NSError **)error
{
    // NSError **error(local copy) = error(passed argument);
    *error = tmp; // Here *error is the pointer to the local error copy,
    // When you dereference error you get NSError *, which you can set,
    // that's your external error.
    return nil;
}
```

Note than it's impossible to do this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSError *otherError = [NSError error with];
*error = otherError;
```

`error` is a pointer to a struct, `*error` is a struct, the one with single `isa` field (from the point of the id type defenition). It's inappropriate to assign pointer to error (`otherError`, i.e. platform pointer size int) to a struct.

And then, the last question remains, why can't you:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSError *otherError = [NSError error with];
*error = *otherError; // why can't I assign to structs?
```

I'm not completely sure, but, maybe memory management and ABI comes in the game, here it could just copy bunch of bytes from one object to another as they are just a C structs.

As you know, Objective-C is a superset of C, and it is possible to assign structs there: [Assign one struct to another in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302351/assign-one-struct-to-another-in-c). That's Objective-C peculiarity dealing with objects, I think. Everything is pretty much dynamic, you can create classes at the runtime and add instance variables ([Mike Ash on that topic](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-6-creating-classes-at-runtime-in-objective-c.html)), so it is not known at the compile time what is beyond the `isa` field in the struct and, actually `id` is just a pointer to that struct with a single `isa`. That's not a good idea to just copy that single `isa` struct and say you're done, things will fall apart.

Comment: @Avi yes, but that should be detected even earlier at compile time, compiler must not allow this, as it is impossible to cast pointer to error to a struct (objective c Object), they are of incompatible type.